# Why don't these assumptions result in further simplification?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify an expression, which has a factor of $\lambda(\lambda-1)$, where $\lambda$ may be either $1$, or $0$. So I try:

```
FullSimplify[λ (λ - 1), λ == 0 || λ == 1]
```

But the expression doesn't simplify to $0$. I've tried changing the assumptions to `λ ∈ Integers && 0 <= λ <= 1`, with the same result.

What's going on? How to convince Mathematica to do the simplification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an equation as an assumption

```
Simplify[λ (λ - 1), λ (λ - 1) == 0]
```

> 0